# WordPress add more tags in wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a WordPress theme.

Core WordPress allow only **Div** and **Nav** tags in wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags.

i want to add one more tag **Select**.

I have added filter in my functions.php

```
apply_filters ( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'select', 'div', 'nav' ) );
```

But it is not working.

What is correct way to tell WordPress about new allow tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use add filter to add your tag:

add filter in **function.php** of current active theme

```
function add_allowed_tags( $allowed ) {   
    array_push($allowed, 'select');
    //print_r($allowed);exit;
    return $allowed;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', 'add_allowed_tags' );
```